# JQuery Progress Circle in Asp.net with C#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am using jQuery Progress Circle in my `.aspx` and client side it's working fine.
how can i populate it with server side values.

**Javascript :**

```
  <script>
    ( function( $ ){
        $( '#circle' ).progressCircle();

        $( '#submit' ).click( function() {
            var nPercent        = $( '#percent' ).val() ? $( '#percent' ).val() : 50;
            var showPercentText = $( '#percentOn' ).prop( 'checked' );
            var circleSize      = $( '#circle-size' ).val() ? $( '#circle-size' ).val() : 100;
            $( '#circle' ).progressCircle({
                nPercent        : nPercent,
                showPercentText : showPercentText,
                circleSize      : circleSize

            });
        })
    })( jQuery );
    </script>
```

The above code is on button click. i want to populate it on the page load of `.cs` page. Please help.

Comment: I would suggest moving the `script` to the back-end, adding the information via concatenation (or similar way) and using `RegisterStartupScript` to place it in the front-end.

Comment: You could also concatenate server-side variables within the `script`. ie: `<%= myVar %>`

Answer (score 0):

Make the controls you use `#percent` and `#percentOn` with `clientIdMode='static'` and `runat='server'` and set them hidden. On page load of the aspx page set the values of the hidden values on server side. Move code in your `submit.click` to document.ready:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
     var nPercent = $( '#percent' ).val() ? $( '#percent' ).val() : 50;
     var showPercentText = $( '#percentOn' ).prop( 'checked' );
     ......
});
```

Comment: my values coming through database how i put the values on hidden fields and  i want to show it on page load.

Comment: On page load you just need to do `percent.Text = 100; percentOn.Text = 70;`, taking 100 and 70 from your database.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**Javascript**

```
<script>
        (function ($) {
            $('#circle').progressCircle();
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var nPercent = $('#<%=hdnprsent.ClientID%>').val();
                var showPercentText = $('#percentOn').prop('checked');
                var thickness = $('#<%=hdnthickness.ClientID%>').val();
                var circleSize = $('#<%=hdncirclesize.ClientID%>').val();
                $('#circle').progressCircle({
                    nPercent: nPercent,
                    showPercentText: showPercentText,
                    thickness: thickness,
                    circleSize: circleSize
                });
            })
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
```

**.CS Code**

Just put the values on hidden fields wherever you wants.

```
hdnprsent.Value = "30";
hdnthickness.Value = "6";
hdncirclesize.Value = "400";
```